# Javascript - Iterate through and array, and re-order its elements

Tags: javascript

**Problem :**

Reformat the below array `openingHours` which may be not a correct structure to have, but that's from where the problem is coming from..

If I do a directly `JSON.parse(openingHours)[0].dayNo1` that would print `08:00 to 04:00` however in this case I need to iterate through the whole array where the key of each element ends by a number.

To iterate through each key, I've done the following :

```
    let dayNo = JSON.parse(openingHours).map((el,index) => {
    let workingHours = el.dayNo+index;
    })
```

However, I'am obtaining a `NaN` and I don't have an idea to go further with it..

**The code:**

```
var hoursArray = [];

var openingHours = [{
"type":"cafe",
"dayNo1": "08:00 to 04:00",
"dayNo2": "08:00 to 01:00",
"dayNo3": "08:00 to 12:00",
"dayNo4": "08:00 to 03:00",
"dayNo5": "08:00 to 19:00",
"dayNo6": "08:00 to 20:00",
"dayNo0": "08:00 to 23:00"
}]

//Get opening hours of days
let dayNo = JSON.parse(openingHours).map((el,index) => {
 let workingHours = el.dayNo+index;

     //Get opening hours of a particular day (for example "08:00 to 04:00" and render it to the following : ["08:00", "04:00"])
let startEndTime = workingHours.split(" to ");

    //Final array format
    hoursArray.push({
    "dayNo":i,
    "operatingHours":{
      "opening": startEndTime[0],
      "closing": startEndTime[1]
    }
  })

 })
```

Comment: so you want an array of all the dayNox ?

Comment: @JoeWarner yes, from `dayNo0` to `dayNo6`

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `map`. Not good.

Comment: `let workingHours = el["dayNo"+index];` is correct, but some other errors are exist.

Comment: `openingHours` is an array containing a single object. Will `openingHours` potentially have more objects or is this it?

Comment: @set0gut1 works but you get only the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data format leaves some questions open. For example, `openingHours` is an array with a single object…will `openingHours` ever have more objects of other `types`?

If we assume that's not the case — that you are just trying to parse this one object — then a simple `for` loop is probably the clearest solution. This is a function that accepts a single object so you can pass it in with `makeHoursObject(openingHours[0])`. This will make it easier if you end up with more than one object in the array:

```js
var openingHours = [{"type":"cafe","dayNo1": "08:00 to 04:00","dayNo2": "08:00 to 01:00","dayNo3": "08:00 to 12:00","dayNo4": "08:00 to 03:00","dayNo5": "08:00 to 19:00","dayNo6": "08:00 to 20:00","dayNo0": "08:00 to 23:00"}]

//Get opening hours of days

function makeHoursObject(obj){
    let hours = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        let day = obj['dayNo'+i]
        if (day == undefined) continue // just in case there's no data for that day
        day = day.split(' to ') 
        hours.push({
            dayNo: i,
            operatingHours: {
             open: day[0], 
             close: day[1]
            }
        })
    }
    return hours
}

console.log(makeHoursObject(openingHours[0]))
```

You can also do this with `reduce`. I think it's a little less clear about the way it works, but might be a little more flexible:

```js
var openingHours = [{"type":"cafe","dayNo1": "08:00 to 04:00","dayNo2": "08:00 to 01:00","dayNo3": "08:00 to 12:00","dayNo4": "08:00 to 03:00","dayNo5": "08:00 to 19:00","dayNo6": "08:00 to 20:00","dayNo0": "08:00 to 23:00"}]

//Get opening hours of days

function makeHoursObject(obj){
   return Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
        let [_, dayNo] = k.split('dayNo')
        if (dayNo != null){
            day = v.split(' to ') 
            a.push({
                dayNo: dayNo,
                operatingHours: {
                 open: day[0], 
                 close: day[1]
                }
            })
        }
        return a
   }, [])
}

console.log(makeHoursObject(openingHours[0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I made some small changes in your code, can you check if is working as you expected?

```
var hoursArray = [];

var openingHours = '{"dayNo1": "08:00 to 04:00","dayNo2": "08:00 to 01:00","dayNo3": "08:00 to 12:00", "dayNo4": "08:00 to 03:00", "dayNo5": "08:00 to 19:00", "dayNo6": "08:00 to 20:00", "dayNo0": "08:00 to 23:00" }'


let x = JSON.parse(openingHours)
var arr = Object.values(x);
arr.map((el, index) => {
  let workingHours = el;

  //Get opening hours of a particular day (for example "08:00 to 04:00" and render it to the following : ["08:00", "04:00"])
  let startEndTime = workingHours.split(" to ");

  //Final array format
  hoursArray.push({
    "dayNo": index,
    "operatingHours": {
      "opening": startEndTime[0],
      "closing": startEndTime[1]
    }
  })

});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sxtcau

Comment: Please don't answer with links.

Comment: I posted the wrong link, but know is the editable one

Comment: Still, nobody wants to click your link. Post the code in the answer itself and explain what it does.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is it written to don`t post links?

Comment: In many, many places. Start here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: That does work, you've even deleted other elements from the array to make it work with your needs

Comment: Hope it helps ;)